# Flutter CupertinoSliverNavigationBar with translated / non constant text?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-cupertino, cupertino-widgets

I am trying to create a view with a CupertinoSliverNavigationBar in Flutter.

```
child: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            const CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
              largeTitle: Text("captureSelectionView.viewTitle").tr(),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter( ...
```

To display the UI in multiple languages, I am using the easy_localization package to translate text, which ususally works perfectly. However, the **CupertinoSliverNavigationBar largeTitle** seems to require a constant because the code above results in an error with VS Code telling me **"Invalid constant value.**". I can't find that it the docs, but the error is there ...

How can I get a dynamic string aka translated text in the largeTitle Text widget?

Thanks for your help!
Best regards,
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `const` from `CupertinoSliverNavigationBar`

```dart
CupertinoSliverNavigationBar(
  largeTitle: Text("captureSelectionView.viewTitle").tr(),
),
```